# Looking for empty lines in Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

When I try to find an empty line textbox I basically cannot achieve that.
The main idea is to check is there any empty lines at the textbox and delete them before saving it all to the text file. "Main" is the name of the TextBox.

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
     {
         int linecount = Main.LineCount;
         for(int i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
         {
             if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Main.GetLineText(i)) == true)
             {
                 Main.Text.Remove(i);
             }
         }
         string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
         File.WriteAllText(path, Main.Text, Encoding.UTF8);
     }
```

I guess the problem is with "empty" lines, because of "\n", or not.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and format your code more readably - it's *very* hard to read at the moment, and it's missing line breaks even in the Markdown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the text at newlines, remove empty strings and write the result to file:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var lines = Main.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var path = @"C:\Temp\MyTest.txt";
    File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
}
```